# filter R dataframe to include only rows with a space between two character strings

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
v1 <- c('abies balsamifera','some trees','pizza','i like tacos','pinus taeda')
v2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
data <- data.frame(v1,v2)
                 v1 v2
1 abies balsamifera  1
2        some trees  2
3             pizza  3
4      i like tacos  4
5       pinus taeda  5
```

I would like to subset the dataframe, only including rows where the character strings in `v1` have two words separated by a space. I want to exclude rows that only have one word, or other rows that have three words. The resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
                 v1 v2
1 abies balsamifera  1
2        some trees  2
5       pinus taeda  5
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for a string that is composed of one or more word characters, a space, and again one or more word characters.

Here is a regular expression which describes the above statement:

```
> grepl('^\\w+\\s\\w+$', v1)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

You can index your data frame with this logical vector.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative counts the number of spaces, allowing for the possibility of more than one adjacent space (eg, a data entry typo).

```
data[sapply(gregexpr(" +", data$v1), function(i) sum(i > 0)) == 1, ]
                 v1 v2
1 abies balsamifera  1
2        some trees  2
5       pinus taeda  5
```

`gregexpr` reads through a character vector and returns a list compsed of vectors of positions that match for each element of the character vector. Non-matches are given (-1), so each the values are compared to 0 and then summed. Values with one match (a single set of adjacent space characters) return TRUE. `sapply` is used to read through the list and returns a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses `strsplit()`. Please note that it is likely slower since it utilizes a loop.

```
v1 <- c('abies balsamifera','some trees','pizza','i like tacos','pinus taeda')
v2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
data <- data.frame(v1,v2)
colnames(data) <- c("v1", "v2")

spacer <- function(data){
    booleans <- vector()
    i <- 1
    while (i <= nrow(data)){
        tmp <- strsplit(as.character(data$v1[i]), ' ')[[1]]
        booleans[i] <- (length(tmp) == 2)
        i <- i + 1
    }
    return(res[(booleans),])
}

data <- spacer(data)
```

output:

```
                 v1 v2
1 abies balsamifera  1
2        some trees  2
5       pinus taeda  5
```

Note: The above code was edited to improve readability and functionality with welcome recommendations from @MatthewLundberg

Comment: You can simplify the code and make it more readable.  First, instead of that `if` statement, just assign directly: `booleans[i] <- length(tmp) == 2`.  Second, there's no reason to bind the `booleans` vector to the data frame, just remove `res$` in the final `return` line of the function.  Then you don't need to remove that column by assigning `NULL`.  And third, as a separate issue, you can create the `booleans` vector to be of the correct length, as you know that it will grow to `nrow(data)` elements.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Thanks for the code review-- I wrote this code quickly to get an answer up (I'm using SO to try to become a better programmer), but I was looking at it later and noticed a lot of unnecessary operations. I'm going to use your recommendations. I really appreciate your time!